# How to avoid gender dependent pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, genderless-pronouns

I have always problem with finding a suitable sentence to avoid a gender dependent pronoun. I know I can use "they" or "their", but if there were other options to totally omit them, I would prefer them.

For example I wrote:

> The user can utilize this information to create appropriate rules to identify **his** items of interest.

Can I here say "the items of interest"?

Are they other options? In general?

Comment: In this case, just omit the pronoun. They are not going to be anyone else's items of interest are they? You won't always be able to circumvent this hoary old problem. If you try, you'll end up like Don Quixote -- tilting at windmills.

Comment: @Mick thanks, you mean "the items of interest" with "the" right?

Comment: Absolutely not. No way. Nada!

Comment: The items of interest don't have to belong to anyone, so you can just say "identify items of interest." I don't know why you can do it, but you can. We need a tame grammarian to tell us why. Maybe one will happen by presently.

Comment: @Mick it seems you mean "zero article" rule.

Comment: Possibly. You do realise that you may know more about English grammar than I do? I had my last English lesson half a century ago. Since then, it has just been "on the job" training -- the university of life, as they say.

Comment: @Mick Maybe, however *articles* are one of the difficult parts of English. It's interesting you know in Persian we don't have any gender-specific pronoun ( we don't discriminate them : ) ).  Moreover we don't have a definite article. If something doesn't have indefinite articles (something like "a" in English before it or a postfix "i") is definite or a generic term.

Answer (score 0):

There are some writers who use

> (s)he

to indicate the subjective third person instead of either *he* or *she*, and

> [hir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hir)

may also be used in place of the objective or possessive *him/his* and *her* to be gender neutral.